# Cannot fetch the sandbox test accounts from paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I was trying to get the details of my sandbox test accounts in paypal unfortunately, it came up empty and just says this

```
We’re sorry, something went wrong while fetching test accounts. Please try again.
```

I also can't see my app in "My apps and credentials" and just says the same thing.

I tried to make a transaction to one of my sandbox test accounts and process the payment flawlessly.

I was wondering how long do I have to wait? or Does paypal have their server overload?

Comment: I experience the same problem. This seems to be happening regularly. I think there is nothing we can do but wait.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue! my apps seem to be gone and I cannot even create a new one

Comment: This has been driving me crazy. for the last few hours I thought I was going stupid. At least I'm not the only one this is not working for.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Is there any way we can get an update about this?

Comment: Same issue here, hopefully it'll get resolved soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
As of February 27, 2017 10:01 PM GMT 8+.
```

It seems the site is back to normal again. I could view my apps and the sandbox test accounts I created.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an issue with PayPal itself, since there are other people with same issue today. We need to wait for PayPal to solve this.

EDIT: Weekend is over, PayPal Sandbox is working! :)